# could not find windowssdkdir variable from the registry

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-xp

After setting toolset "Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)" got this warning and related errors in

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
```

How can i fix it?